# Restoring MS Project Views

Tags: ms-project

I'm running a user defined script that changes the view during the course of its computations. When I launch the VBA script, the view is in no particular filter, table or view name. I want to restore the view just as it was before the user launched the script including which task has the focus. It seems like naming the view as the first step when the script launches and saving the task which has focus then activating the view and focus at the completion of the script is a potential way to do this but I'm not having any success. I would delete the named view at the end of running the script. Any suggestions or point me to previous discussions on this forum that may have answered; my search didn't reveal any.

Rod Gill suggested the following but unless I'm doing something wrong it doesn't appear to work.

```
Dim OrgnlID As Long
Dim OrgnlView As String
Dim OrgnlTable As String
Dim OrgnlFilter As String

OrgnlView = ActiveProject.CurrentView
OrgnlTable = ActiveProject.CurrentTable
OrgnlFilter = ActiveProject.CurrentFilter
OrgnlID = ActiveCell.Issue

' place your code here that does the view manipulations
' followed by the lines below to restore the view before manipulations

ViewApply OrgnlView
TableApply OrgnlTable
FilterApply OrgnlFilter
EditGoTo ID:=OrgnlID
```

Comment: The setting of OrgnlID is incorrect, do this instead: `OrgnlID = ActiveCell.Task.ID`.

Comment: Forgot to say that I commented out that line to get around the error which your correction should repair. However, the other code still does not work. For instance, rows which were visible and which I collapsed during the pause and columns that were visible and which I hid during the pause are not restored by the apply statements.

Comment: The conversation on the MS forum is here.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_project-mso_win10-mso_2016/restoring-views-after-running-script/cef95426-efa2-4528-bf63-1194ca5e5509?tm=1547858548178&auth=1

Comment: When columns are hidden, the table definition is automatically updated, so if you must hide them either insert the columns back or make a new temporary table to use during the macro. Similarly for rows, the best thing to do would be to not collapse them at all during the macro, but if you have to, expand all tasks at the end of the macro.